# Equivalent notion of nowhere dense.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

would anyone know how to manage to show the equivalence below? The Forward implication is clear to me, however, the backward direction is allude me, I'm afraid.

Let $M$ be a metric space. A subset $E$ of $M$ is nowhere dense if, and only if, for each point $x \in M$ and $r > 0$, there exists a point $y \in B_r(x) = \{w \in M : d(x,w) < r\}$ and an $s > 0$ such that $B_s(y) \subset B_r(x)$ and $B_s(y) \cap E = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prove that $E$ is nowhere dense, we must show that $\overline{E}$ does not contain any open set.
Suppose by contradiction that it does contain an open set.
That is, suppose there exists $x\in M$ and $r>0$ such that $B_r(x) \subseteq \overline{E}$. By hypothesis there is $y\in M$ and $s>0$ such that
$B_s(y)\subseteq B_r(x)$ and $B_s(y)\cap E = \emptyset$.
From the condition $B_s(y)\cap E=\emptyset$, we infer $y\not\in\overline{E}$. But
$y\in B_s(y)\subseteq B_r(x)\subseteq\overline{E}$. Contradiction!

Comment: I had actually considered an argument like this, but the only part I'm not clear on is where you conclude that $y \not \in \overline{E}$. Isn't it possible for it to exist in $\partial E$ and hence in $\overline{E}$? That's honestly the only point of concern I would have--if it's obvious, I feel kind of bad... Thanks! : )

Comment: @m2271r The closure of a set $E$ in a topological space (or in a metric space) is equal to the set of all points $y$ such that, for every open set $U$ containing $y$, we have $U\cap E\ne\emptyset$. Try proving this if this is something you haven't seen before. (And of course post here or in another question if you get stuck.)

Comment: Oh no, I see! I haven't seen that formulation in about 3 years, so it makes sense. Good point, $x \in \overline{E}$ if and only if $B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap E \neq \emptyset$ for every $\epsilon>0$. That makes sense. Thank you!